# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

Tags: python, tensorflow, terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Tensorflow can exactly work at jupyter notebook, but when I try to

```
import tensorflow
```

at pycharm or just in ternminal, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/g-odi/Downloads/ipy/Deep-Learning-with-TensorFlow-book/ch03/main.py", line 5, in 
<module>
import  tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\g-odi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\facat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", 
line 98, in <module>
from tensorflow_core import *
File "C:\Users\g-odi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\facat\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package
```

pycharm can find tensorflow in interpreter:
[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR2bz.png)

tensorflow has been install, I can use it at jupyter or ipython
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAKEo.png)

Comment: Check what interpreter you defined to your project in Pycharm, probably you the in interpreter  defined doesn't have tensor flow

Comment: You can see tensorflow in the photo I attached

Comment: You are working with conda env,
open conda prompt with cmd, click 'conda activate facat', and write conda list. If you dont see tensorflow, write 'conda install tensorflow". if you do see it, try to open a new project using the same virtual env.

Comment: I had installed it, you can see the image I updated

Comment: You didn't understand me. In python you work with different environments. In the one you run your project with, tf isn't installed. I you follow my previous instructions it will fix your problem

Comment: I do see it, then a new project also occupy the same error, I think it's because there is something wrong in the progress of importing, not simply because tf isn't installed(Or the traceback will be only "No module named 'tensorflow" ).

Comment: @Facet were you able to solve the problem? I am facing the same issue.