# tensorflow : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I try to run

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

at pycharm , then I got the error message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package

I refer to questions like [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006355/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python-tools-tensorflow-pyth/61673795#61673795) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116456/no-module-named-tensorflow-python-tools-tensorflow-python-is-not-a-package) , they are just to recommend downgrade or reinstalling.

**The particularity of this problem is** ：

1. [cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMMxR.png) When I run `import tensorflow` in cmd ,it works well.
2. The code of this project is correct because I 'have run it on other computer .And I use CONDA to keep the environment consistent.

**I have checked the interpreter of pycharm and this project and it was correct .**

How can I resolve it ? I have fight with this problems for 3 days.

Comment: Do you have a file called tensorflow.py in your project or in your PATH?

Comment: No, I have read a question like 'change the file name **tensorflow.py** to another name' .But I have no file name like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with you. I found it is the pycharm to be blamed. In tensorflow version later than 2.0.0, the main functions of tensorflow is located in tensorflow_core instead of the folder tensorflow like tensorflow 1.x. When you use cmd, python can find these packages(by some methods), but the pycharm of old version cannot. So update your pycharm or use earlier versions of tensorflow might solve your problem.
[Unable to import Keras(from TensorFlow 2.0) in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188704/unable-to-import-kerasfrom-tensorflow-2-0-in-pycharm). these question said that PyCharm can recognises tensorflow 2.0.0b1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer will solve my problem . Yes , I mentioned that I have run the project successfully in the another PC and it goes well . **There are 2 versions PyCharm between both of PC .**